# SharePoint Calculated field If statement adding leading zero's

Tags: sharepoint

In a SharePoint document Library I need the ID to have leading zero's zo the string is a minimal of 4 digits:

0001
0099
0999
9999
19999

I'm trying this, but it only works if Itemnumber_test is 0:

if([c_itemNumber_test]>0,if([c_itemNumber_test]<10,"3 leading zeros",if([c_itemNumber_test]<100,"2 leading zeros",if([c_itemNumber_test]<1000,"1 leading zero",[c_itemNumber]))),"")

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in calcualted column:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0",MAX(0,4-LEN(ID))),ID)
```

Result:

[image]